# Is there any joke in last line?

Tags: jokes

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), a plaintiff attorney, Rohr meets Ranking Fitch, a jury consultant of the defendants,
the gun manufacturers:

> Rohr: Nice suit. Very "of the people."
>
> Fitch: Yours is nicer. What
> would you call it, "gun lobby protecting its own"? Swank shoes.
>
> Rohr: Big tobacco?
>
> Fitch: **Big alligator. Wrestled it myself.**

Is there any joke in last line?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'Big tobacco' means, but presumably the shoes are alligator-skin and Fitch jokes that he personally killed the alligator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Rohr is asking "Are the expensive alligator leather shoes paid for from earnings made by defending large tobacco companies against lawsuits?"

"Big tobacco" is a
metonymy for "Large tobacco companies"  (compare "Big Pharma" or "Big oil").  Fitch turns this around, using "big" literally as "No, they came from a large American crocodile". There is wit here, but it's not really a "joke". He claims to have caught (and killed) it himself. I don't know if I believe him. Is he usually trustworthy?